# Radians error message with Lat / Lon calculation

Tags: php, mysql, latitude-longitude, radians

I'm creating a website with an events calendar where users search by location (lon/lat) and I found this online which has a calculation but I keep getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function RADIANS() in ...

Why I may be getting this?

My calculation is:

```
$calc = 6378.137 * acos( Cos( RADIANS(lat) ) * Cos( RADIANS('$yourlat') ) * Cos( RADIANS('$yourlon') - RADIANS(lon) ) + Sin( RADIANS(lat) ) * Sin( RADIANS('$yourat')));

$get_events_sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE '$calc' <= 10";
```

Comment: Are you seeing that as a php error, or a MySQL one?

Comment: try calling method RADIANS as $this->RADIANS or if it lies in namespace use \RADIANS or \..fully qualified namespace path..\RADIANS whatever in your case.

Answer (score 1):

RADIANS is a MySQL function, but you're trying to call it in php. If you want to convert degrees to radians in PHP, you can define this function.

```
    function RADIANS($degrees)
    {
         return 0.0174532925 * $degrees;
    }
```

Or, you can just multiply by that constant.  (360 degrees is 2π radians)

Comment: Thanks, I got the calculation to work, it turned out that I hadn't put a . before the = on the code I wanted to output so it was only ever showing one result. The code seemed to be working without using this function and when I drop this in it doesn't make any difference to the search result output. Any Ideas why that is?